# react native push notification not display when app in background on ios

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-firebase

I have react native application until now I used react-native-firebase version 5.5.6 (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-firebase/v/5.5.6) to recived push notification and every work fine in android and ios.
now i upgrade to react-native-firebase version 11.1.2 and react-native-firebase/messaging version 11.1.2.
in android the notification work fine in all app state (foreground, background, closed)
in ios when app in foreground the notification recived fine but in in background or closed app the notification not showing
I mark the remote notification and fetch notification in background modes in xcode
when the in foreground and i received notification this is json i received

```
{
aps =     {
    alert =         {
        body = "\nCat. No.: 34612\nAddress: \U05d1\U05e0\U05d9\U05d9\U05df \U05e2\U05d9\U05e8\U05d9\U05d9\U05d4 \U05d1\nFloor: 2\nReported about: Intercoms    \nStatus: Your call has been received\n Description: check\n Full name: \U05d2\U05dc\U05d7\U05d1\U05d7 \U05dc\U05d1\U05d9\U05d0\U05d7\U05d2\U05d7";
        title = "New message about a service call";
    };
    badge = 2;
    "content-available" = 1;
    "mutable-content" = 1;
};
"custom_notification" = "{\"title\":\"New message about a service call\",\"body\":\"\\nCat. No.: 34612\\nAddress: \U05d1\U05e0\U05d9\U05d9\U05df \U05e2\U05d9\U05e8\U05d9\U05d9\U05d4 \U05d1\\nFloor: 2\\nReported about: Intercoms    \\nStatus: Your call has been received\\n Description: check\\n Full name: \U05d2\U05dc\U05d7\U05d1\U05d7 \U05dc\U05d1\U05d9\U05d0\U05d7\U05d2\U05d7\",\"show_in_foreground\":true,\"icon\":\"push_notification\",\"sound\":\"default\"}";
deepLink = "https://darimpo-test.appspot.com/#openApplication?serviceCallId=34612&taskPostId=151288";
"fcm_options" =     {
    image = "https://storage.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/darimpo_test_images/o/8551.jpg?generation=1615666155330439&alt=media";
};
"gcm.message_id" = 1616606515037965;
"google.c.a.e" = 1;
"show_in_foreground" = "{\"title\":\"New message about a service call\",\"body\":\"\\nCat. No.: 34612\\nAddress: \U05d1\U05e0\U05d9\U05d9\U05df \U05e2\U05d9\U05e8\U05d9\U05d9\U05d4 \U05d1\\nFloor: 2\\nReported about: Intercoms    \\nStatus: Your call has been received\\n Description: check\\n Full name: \U05d2\U05dc\U05d7\U05d1\U05d7 \U05dc\U05d1\U05d9\U05d0\U05d7\U05d2\U05d7\",\"show_in_foreground\":true,\"icon\":\"push_notification\",\"sound\":\"default\"}";
```

}

maybe you now why is not working for me
thank you

Comment: Hi 
I add   messaging().setAutoInitEnabled(true);
            messaging().registerDeviceForRemoteMessages();
in react native and now the bagde changed but the notification not showing in status bar.
not in background and not in closed app state

Comment: Hi 
I think all push I sent is silent push this is why the notification not display
maybe you know why is setup has silent push